# Too Much Time to load Select Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a query, and it's taking around 1 minute and 40 seconds to give output and sometime take more than 2 or 3 minutes. Can anyone help and tell me why it's taking this much time? The output result is around 409799 rows.

```
Select 
 Distinct
 A.ID
 ,tracactionId Contracid
 ,Cancaldate 
,Suppliers
,Ct.Type "Contract Type"
,Sitename "Site Name" 
,St.Telephone "Site Telephone"
,Cc.Mobile
,At.Type "Action Type"
,Ms.Status "Order Status"
,Name Client
,Ass.Status
 ,Isnull(
     Case When Try_Parse(orderac As Numeric(10,2)) <= '60000' Then 'T3' 
     When Try_Parse(orderac As Numeric(10,2)) >= '60001' And 
    Try_Parse(orderac As Numeric(10,2)) <= '1000000' Then 'T2' 
     When Try_Parse(orderac As Numeric(10,2)) >= '1000001'  Then 'T1' End, 
   '-') "Consumption Order"
   ,Isnull(
     Case When Try_Parse(Replaceaq As Numeric(10,2)) <= '60000' Then 'T3' 
     When Try_Parse(Replaceaq As Numeric(10,2)) >= '60001' And 
  Try_Parse(Replaceaq As Numeric(10,2)) <= '1000000' Then 'T2' 
     When Try_Parse(Replaceaq As Numeric(10,2)) >= '1000001'  Then 'T1' End, 
   '-') "Consumption Replace"
  ,Case When Datepart(Day, Cancaldate ) > 21 And Cancaldate  < '9999-12-01'
  Then Substring(Datename(Month, Dateadd(Month, 1, Cancaldate )), 1, 3) + ' 
  ' + Datename(Year, Dateadd(Month, 1, Cancaldate ))
  Else Substring(Datename(Month, Cancaldate ), 1, 3) + ' ' + Datename(Year, 
  Cancaldate ) End As "Month Year"
   From return A
   Left  Hash Join Contract C On C.Contractid = A.contractid
                                                 And orderdate In (Select 
  Max(Aa.orderdate) From Return Aa Where Aa.Contractid = A.Contractid)
 Left  Hash Join Suppliers S On S.Suppliersid = C.Supplierid
  Left  Hash Join ordercontract Mc On Mc.Contractid = C.Contractid
 Left  Hash Join order M On M.orderid = Mc.orderid
 Left  Hash Join Contracttype Ct On C.Contracttypeid= Ct.ordercontracttypeid
 Left  Hash Join Site St On St.Siteid = C.Siteid
  Inner Hash Join ordersubtype Ast On Ast.ordersubtypeid = A.Aordersubtypeid
 Inner Hash Join ordertype At On At.ordertypeid = A.ordertypeid
 Left  Hash Join oderstatus Ms On Ms.orderstatusid = M.orderstatusid 
  Inner Hash Join Users U On U.Userid = A.userid
 Inner Hash Join orderstatus Ass On Ass.orderstatusid = A.orderstatusid
 Inner Hash Join product On A.productid = product.productid
 Inner Hash Join Contact Cc On product.Maincontactid = Cc.Contactid
 where  M.Meterstatusid <> 8
```

This is the execution plan and its suggestion to create a non-clustered index.

I'm new to this; please help me out.

```
/*
Missing Index Details from SQLQuery2.sql - 10.0.1.9.EnergyCRM_Main 
(adminlocal (84))
 The Query Processor estimates that implementing the following index could 
 improve the query cost by 15.558%.
 */

  /*
 USE [SAmpler]
   GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
 ON [dbo].[Action] ([orderID])
INCLUDE ([orderTypeID],[orderStatusID],[productID],[orderDate],
 [AssignedToUserID],[orderSubTypeID])
  GO
  */
```

Comment: Have a look at the execution plan and see for yourself

Comment: we cannot run your query on your database so its hard to help you. If you want help than add the actual execution plan in your question

Comment: That query looks like a mismatch of _I've read on some website_ techniques without understading, that I would say you'd properly would be a lot better off rewriting it from scratch and possible specializing the query into smaller ones - rather than trying to fix it, especially by simply adding more indexes to your database.

Comment: Distinct clause also makes slow, in your query DISTINCT is required?

Comment: Yes @SandipPatel

Comment: With that formatting it is hard to follow.   For one joins are not logically ordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just making some sense of this mess

You need to indicate what tables the columns come from
Not clear all the tables are even used

All the Try_Parse is a problem

Table join hints should be a last resort

```
Select Distinct
       A.ID
     , tracactionId Contracid
     , Cancaldate 
     , Suppliers
     , Ct.Type "Contract Type"
     , Sitename "Site Name" 
     , St.Telephone "Site Telephone"
     , Cc.Mobile
     , At.Type "Action Type"
     , Ms.Status "Order Status"
     , Name Client
     , Ass.Status  
     , Isnull( Case When Try_Parse(orderac As Numeric(10,2)) <= '60000'   Then 'T3'
                    When Try_Parse(orderac As Numeric(10,2)) >= '60001' 
                     And Try_Parse(orderac As Numeric(10,2)) <= '1000000' Then 'T2' 
                    When Try_Parse(orderac As Numeric(10,2)) >= '1000001' Then 'T1' 
               End
               , '-'
             ) "Consumption Order"
     , Isnull( Case When Try_Parse(Replaceaq As Numeric(10,2)) <= '60000' Then 'T3'
                    When Try_Parse(Replaceaq As Numeric(10,2)) >= '60001' 
                     And Try_Parse(Replaceaq As Numeric(10,2)) <= '1000000' Then 'T2' 
                    When Try_Parse(Replaceaq As Numeric(10,2)) >= '1000001' Then 'T1' 
               End
               , '-'
             ) "Consumption Replace"
    , Case When Datepart(Day, Cancaldate ) > 21 And Cancaldate  < '9999-12-01'  
                Then Substring(Datename(Month, Dateadd(Month, 1, Cancaldate )), 1, 3) 
                     + ' ' + Datename(Year, Dateadd(Month, 1, Cancaldate ))
           Else Substring(Datename(Month, Cancaldate ), 1, 3) 
                + ' ' + Datename(Year, Cancaldate ) 
      End As "Month Year"
From return A

Inner Hash Join ordersubtype Ast On Ast.ordersubtypeid = A.Aordersubtypeid

Inner Hash Join ordertype At     On At.ordertypeid     = A.ordertypeid 

Inner Hash Join orderstatus Ass  On Ass.orderstatusid  = A.orderstatusid

Inner Hash Join Users U On U.Userid                    = A.userid

Inner Hash Join product On product.productid           = A.productid 
Inner Hash Join Contact Cc On Cc.Contactid = product.Maincontactid 

Left Hash Join Contract C 
  On C.Contractid                                      = A.contractid
 And orderdate In ( Select Max(Aa.orderdate) 
                    From Return Aa 
                    Where Aa.Contractid = A.Contractid 
                  )
Left  Hash Join Suppliers S On S.Suppliersid               = C.Supplierid      
Left  Hash Join Contracttype Ct On  Ct.ordercontracttypeid = C.Contracttypeid    
Left  Hash Join Site St On St.Siteid                       = C.Siteid

Left  Hash Join ordercontract Mc On Mc.Contractid          = C.Contractid  
Left  Hash Join order M On M.orderid = Mc.orderid
Left  Hash Join oderstatus Ms On Ms.orderstatusid = M.orderstatusid 

where  M.Meterstatusid <> 8
```

Answer (score 3):

This question is really hard to answer without an execution plan. 
Looking at the code I suspect a couple of things;

- ISNULL generally hurts performance when used on indexed columns since it prohibits the use of said indexes
- Why are all joins specified as hash joins? In most cases it is best to let the query optimizer decide which join is fastest.
- I see a lot of try_parse, it might be a consideration to check/ process the columns beforehand and set them to the desired datatype. In that case you don't have to check for every column if it is the correct datatype.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, since we cannot perform the actual query. My best guess is that all your ISNULL's are hurting performance.

Try this:

```
Case When Try_Parse(orderac As Numeric(10,2)) <= '60000' Then 'T3' 
     When Try_Parse(orderac As Numeric(10,2)) >= '60001' And 
     Try_Parse(orderac As Numeric(10,2)) <= '1000000' Then 'T2' 
     When Try_Parse(orderac As Numeric(10,2)) >= '1000001'  Then 'T1' 
     ELSE '-' End AS "Consumption Order"
```

Comment: No Its same  taking time well I add the Execution Plan